# What could be the reasons of not getting output after counting BAM file?

Tags: r, bioinformatics, bioconductor

I have a question, I performed trimming and alignemnt of my paired-end RNA-seq samples based on "hg38.knownGene.gtf" and I got .bam file for each sample. When I have tried this BAM file in GenomicAlignments package for counting reads, the output file is empty. Below is the code that I used for counting:
Anybody knows what could be the reasons of this problem? I used same reference "hg38.knownGene.gtf" as alignment step.

- I'm using latest version of desktop Rstudio.

```
input<- ("input.bam")
#total size of BAM file is around 2GB so, I used yieldSize to call .bam file.
data.FL <- BamFileList(input, yieldSize = 3000000) 
# reference file
gtf.file<-"hg38.knownGene.gtf"  #ucsc
TxDb<-makeTxDbFromGFF(gtf.file,format="gtf")

#GrangesList
exons<-exonsBy(TxDb,by="gene")
transcripts<-transcriptsBy(TxDb,by="gene") 
grl<-GRangesList(c(exons,transcripts))

#counting
data<-summarizeOverlaps(grl,data.FL,mode = "Union",singleEnd=F,ignore.strand=TRUE)

#writing the output in .csv:
vector <- as.vector(mcols(data)$data)
write.csv(vector,"vector.csv")
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Why do you have the "python" tag?

Answer (score 1):

I will make a general comment rather than addressing the tchnical part:

Use standard software for counting reads over genes, intervals or regions. That can be something like featureCounts which is available as both a standalone tool for the command line and also has an R package called Rsubread to do that from inside R. Don't do custom approaches for something as standard as that. It really makes no sense to read an entire BAM file into memory, that's most inefficient. featureCounts will do that better, with low memory footprint and in almost no time.